# Airplay not working - OpenElec/Gotham/R-Pi

Tags: kodi, openelec

I have an R-Pi (Model B) with OpenElec 4.0.6 (which implies XBMC 13.1). I can't get any Airplay devices talking to it. I try with my phone and I get video can not be played messages, or crashes in the App. <del>Mac OSX can't even see it.</del>

I remember seeing some posts about improved Airplay support in XBMC 13.x, is it still in flux? Are there any tweaks that I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Airplay on a macbook includes 'Mirroring' and is not supported by Xbmc. I have issues now too with iOS8, but iOS7 should just work. Try playing a youtube video.

Comment: @gotschi neither YouTube nor Amazon video work. Thanks for MacBook info

Answer (score 1):

I know IOS9 isn't yet supported. Stay tuned to [this site](https://github.com/juhovh/shairplay/issues/43) fro more info. Also, if that doesn't work, maybe I can try to code an alternative to Google Remote Desktop, or something like that. Let me know.

Comment: I had the same issue with my GF's iphone, when your device is on ios9, you're out of luck